# How to add a new field to the plone.app.discussion comment in plone4

Tags: comments, plone

i want to add a new field email to plone.app.discussion comment for anonymous users . I have searched in google and found two approaches.
**Approach1:** using quintagroup product "quintagroup.plonecommments". With this approach my plone is getting crashed.
**Approach2:** Following the procedure given in the URL : http://packages.python.org/plone.app.discussion/howtos/howto_extend_the_comment_form.html. This approach is not working. 

Can anyone help me with any solution for my requirement.

### Traceback of Approach1:

Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module plone.z3cform.layout, line 71, in **call**
Module plone.z3cform.layout, line 91, in render
Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 125, in **call**
Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 59, in **call**
Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 113, in pt_render
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in **call**
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 405, in do_startTag
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 482, in attrAction_tal
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 225, in evaluateText
Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
- URL: c:\plone41\eggs\plone.app.discussion-2.0.10-py2.6.egg\plone\app\discussion\browser\controlpanel.pt
- Line 17, Column 0
- Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'view/settings'>
- Names:
{'args': (),
'container': <PloneSite at /test>,
'context': <PloneSite at /test>,
'default': <object object at 0x00991830>,
'here': <PloneSite at /test>,
'loop': {},
'nothing': None,
'options': {},
'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x06995CF0>,
'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/test/@@discussion-settings>,
'root': <Application at >,
'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x051C5490>,
'traverse_subpath': [],
'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,
'view': <Products.Five.metaclass.DiscussionSettingsControlPanel object at 0x06AF07B0>,
'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x06A28450>}
Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in **call**
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 155, in _eval
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 117, in render
Module plone.app.discussion.browser.controlpanel, line 128, in settings
IndexError: tuple index out of range

**For Approach2 i have not got any errors but nothing is reflected in the site.**

Comment: Tell us *how* these two approaches are failing for you as well. Full tracebacks please!

Comment: Approach 2 is the documented method of extending `plone.app.discussion`. I think you must have done *something* wrong to not get any results, but we cannot help you because you didn't share enough information for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The error trace you provided looks like a know plone.app.discussion bug. Please upgrade to plone.app.discussion 2.1.5 to fix it.

As Martijn already pointed out, you have to provide more information and full tracebacks, otherwise people can't really help you. Just providing "This approach is not working." makes it impossible for people to help.